# Edit first column of GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I've got very dynamic GridView and I need to allow to user to edit first column of it. After he edit first column of grid it must be updated on DataBase.

Is there any ways to handle it ?

My only idea is to put some changeable element to first cell of each Row so it must be able to set / get my values for each row but can't find yet any examples of it ...

Additional info :
GridView takes data from Object data source and all columns are dynamic (yes, maybe except first, but I add it in dynamic way) and load complete DataTable... \

Currently Using jQuery+Ajax methode on dynamic button but can't disable button's PostBack so with a PostBack it just disappears and dont make the event it must to make...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have dymanic columns, for each column, specify the `read-only` property (If a column is read-only, it may only be looked at, and not edited when in the GridView's Edit-Mode).

So, the first column of would be `readonly="false"` (or omit it entirely) and the other columns `read-only="true"`.